# Pandas convert data type of a column but not of its content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, dtype

I have a dataframe df, where column "number" has object datatype:

```
>>>df['number'].dtype
dtype('O')
```

After I save it and load again, pandas assumes that "number" column is int:

```
>>>df_muster['number'].dtype
dtype('int64')
```

I actually want to compare these two dataframes, so I am assigning object dtype to the second one:

```
>>>df_muster['number']=df_muster['number'].astype('O')
>>>df_muster['number'].dtype
dtype('O')
```

But if check inside, values are not strings, compared to initial dataframe, and correspondingly, I still cannot compare these two dataframes:

```
>>>df_muster['number'][0]
4508721256
>>>df_muster['number'].values[0]
4508721256
>>>df['number'][0]
'4508721256'
```

I just want to know why does it happen and how can I enforce convertion of every number of a column to object?

p.s. I know that other way round it works, so I can convert dtype of df to int64, but only if all numbers are in place, if there are None values I get an error. Columns with Nones I can convert to float, but again convertion of float64 to obj does not work as expected, only column dtype changes, but inside numbers stay numbers.

Comment: my question is not why dtype change after save-read to csv, but how to convert int/float to objects..

Comment: so need `.astype('str')` ?

Comment: i think str is not possible in pandas, so .astype("O")

Comment: is possible, but not sure if help here...