# How to convert column data type object to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, floating-point

I am trying to convert this column type into float from object type. How to solve it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['[-0.8783137, 0.05478287, -0.08827557, 0.69203985, 0.06209986]', 
                            '[0.31444644, -0.6546649, 0.7211526, 0.9819127, 0.74042267]']})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'. Did you mean: 'infer_objects'?   after trying from that solution

Comment: It's clearly written there that. `pd.convert_objects has now been deprecated. You should use pd.Series.astype(float) or pd.to_numeric`

Comment: tried but doesn't work

Comment: Could you just... upload the desired (final) output? @BadrunNessaAntu

Comment: Because what I can understand from here is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701721/pandas-convert-data-type-of-a-column-but-not-of-its-content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence error is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040643/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-error-is-showing)

Comment: @gre_gor No Btw that was my post.

Comment: @BadrunNessaAntu I know. It looks to me like you are reposting the question.

Comment: @gre_gor same datatype with different error I had faced.

Comment: @BadrunNessaAntu You never posted any errors.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1: If need convert list of strings to list of floats:

```
#change sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [['-0.8783137', '0.05478287', '-0.08827557', '0.69203985', '0.06209986'], 
                            ['0.31444644', '-0.6546649', '0.7211526', '0.9819127', '0.74042267']]})
```

---

```
#dtype of lists is object
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672574/2901002
print (df['col1'].dtype)
object

#first value of column col1
print (df.loc[0, 'col1'])
['-0.8783137', '0.05478287', '-0.08827557', '0.69203985', '0.06209986']

#type of first value of column col1 is list
print (type(df.loc[0, 'col1']))
<class 'list'>

#first value of column col1 and first value of list
print (df.loc[0, 'col1'][0])
-0.8783137

#first value of column col1 and type of first value of list
print (type(df.loc[0, 'col1'][0]))
<class 'str'>
```

---

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x])
#another solution
df['col1'] = [[float(y) for y in x] for x in df['col1']]

print (df)
                                                col1
0  [-0.8783137, 0.05478287, -0.08827557, 0.692039...
1  [0.31444644, -0.6546649, 0.7211526, 0.9819127,...
```

---

```
#dtype of lists is object
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672574/2901002
print (df['col1'].dtype)
object
    
#first value of column col1
print (df.loc[0, 'col1'])
[-0.8783137, 0.05478287, -0.08827557, 0.69203985, 0.06209986]

#type of first value of column col1 is list
print (type(df.loc[0, 'col1']))
<class 'list'>

#first value of column col1 and first value of list
print (df.loc[0, 'col1'][0])
-0.8783137

#first value of column col1 and type of first value of list
print (type(df.loc[0, 'col1'][0]))
<class 'float'>
```

EDIT2: If need DataFrame from lists - each list has same length:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].tolist(), index=df.index).astype(float)
print (df2)
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.878314  0.054783 -0.088276  0.692040  0.062100
1  0.314446 -0.654665  0.721153  0.981913  0.740423
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253211/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-how-to-convert-column-data-type-object-to-float); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try -

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('float')
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['[-0.8783137, 0.05478287, -0.08827557, 0.69203985, 0.06209986]', 
                            '[0.31444644, -0.6546649, 0.7211526, 0.9819127, 0.74042267]']})

df['col1'] = [json.loads(e) for e in df['col1']]
```

**Check first value**

```py
>>> print(type(df.iloc[0,0]))
<class 'list'>
```

This is a list of float values.

Comment: doesn't work.. each of the row is having 768 values

Comment: For me it's working perfectly (with your code sample) ???

Comment: I can't put 768 values here so put these values... but in my real dataframe it is giving error

Comment: I just modify my answer

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list this error this showing